# XSD elements in C#

Tags: c#

I have an XSD file and I need to get a list of the names of all the elements in it.

I tried the following:

```
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
tbSchema.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;

cbElement.Items.Clear();

XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemaSet.Add("", tbSchema.Text);
schemaSet.Compile();
XmlSchema customerSchema = null;
foreach (XmlSchema schema in schemaSet.Schemas())
{
    customerSchema = schema;
}
foreach (XmlSchemaElement element in customerSchema.Elements.Values)
{
    cbElement.Items.Add(element.Name);
}
```

but it still does not work.

Comment: Load the file into an `XDocument` and use LINQ to XML to query it. XSD files are XML, after all.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:-

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.Load("D:\\schema.xsd");                      // Load the document from the root of an ASP.Net website

 XmlElement schemaElement = doc.DocumentElement;  // The root element of the schema document is the <schema> element
 string elementName = schemaElement.LocalName;    // This will print "schema"
 foreach (XmlNode ele in schemaElement.ChildNodes)
 {
  if (ele.LocalName == "element")
  {
     .....
  }
 }
```

Comment: thank you Rahul, but how shoul I continue: I need the name of all Elements from xsd: `</xs:element> <xs:element name="RuntimeSettings"> <xs:complexType> <xs:all> `